# Node js Nested Promise.all error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

```
exports.AllDataCounts= function(req, res) {
  var UserId = req.params.User_Id;
  Promise.all([
           Model.SchemaOne.count({ User_Id: UserId }).exec(),
           Model.SchemaTwo.find({ User_Id: UserId }).exec()
  ]).then(response_One => {
     console.log('response_One Success');
     var _ids = response_One[1].map(x => x._id );

     const GetMoreInfo = _id => {
             Promise.all([
                  Model.Cube_SchemaThree.count({ Cube_Id: _id }).exec(),
                  Model.Cube_SchemaFour.count({ Cube_Id: _id }).exec(),
             ]).then( response_three => {
                 console.log('response_three Success');
                 return response_three ;
              }).catch(error_3 => {
                 console.log('error');
                 return Cube_Id;
               });  
     };
     Promise.all(
           _ids.map(_id=> GetMoreInfo(_id))
     ).then(response_two => {
        console.log('response_two Success'); 
        res.send({ Status:true, Response: { Output1: response_One, Output3: response_two });
     }).catch( error_two = > {
        res.send({ Status: false, Error: error_two, Message: 'Some Error Occurred' });
     });
  }).catch( error_one = > {
     res.send({ Status: false, Error: error_1, Message: 'Some Error Occurred' });
  });
};
```

i will expect the console output is

> response_One Success
>
> response_three Success
>
> response_Two Success

but i got the result is

> response_One Success
>
> response_Two Success
>
> response_Three Success

if i will remove the GetMoreInfo function inside Promise.all it works properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
const GetMoreInfo= _id => {
  Promise.all([
    Model.Cube_SchemaThree.count({ Cube_Id: _id }).exec(),
    Model.Cube_SchemaFour.count({ Cube_Id: _id }).exec(),
  ]).then(
```

`getMoreInfo` isn't returning its `Promise.all`, so it's not being properly included in the larger promise chain when you call

```
Promise.all(
  _ids.map(_id=> GetMoreInfo(_id))
).then( ...
```

(rather, currently, the `.then` there will resolve immediately because the `Promise.all` is being called on an array of `undefined`s, which is not what you want)

Change to:

```
const GetMoreInfo= _id => {
  return Promise.all([
    // ...
```